# Add a column from one table to another table with same constraints

Tags: mysql

How can I add a column from one table to another with same constraints

For example:-
Table 1 has
id name age
Table 2 has
id name gender

now I want to add a column gender in table 1 with the same properties as mentioned in table 2 Like gender has character of length 1 and could not be set to null, but the catch is I don't know the properties of gender and it should automatically add all properties.

Comment: what sql query should be written for the same.

Comment: You can get the properties of a column by doing "SHOW COLUMNS FROM Table WHERE Field='gender'", then you could process the result and alter the table you want to update.